# Star icon in roGridScreen breadcrumb

Tags: roku, brightscript

In Roku BrightScript, is there any way to use the star icon on the info button on the Roku remote control in the breadcrumb at the top right of the [roGridScreen](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/roGridScreen)? The intention is to indicate to users that they can press the info button to access a settings view.

The closest I've gotten is by using the * text string (`gridScreen.SetBreadcrumbText("Settings *", "")`), but that doesn't look nearly as convincing as the icon in Roku's own Home interface to the right of the word "Options".

A way to use a custom image in the breadcrumb would do the trick or perhaps a character code for use with `Chr()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try U+272A (Circled white star), though i doubt they have that exact one in the font.

You can probably show something in the corner by using clever overhang graphic.

Third idea: i think RokuCo have added star-in-square somewhere in their font; it just draws so much like the rest of the crumb text. So try what shows for... well, most of Unicode till you find it?

Comment: The solution with the overhang graphic worked. There are actually two ways of doing it, either by embedding the graphic in the logo (`GridScreenLogoHD`) or in the overhang slice (`GridScreenOverhangSliceHD `). Whichever image you pick, it has to be made as wide as the screen to get the star in the correct spot on the right.


This was confirmed in the [Roku developer forum](http://forums.roku.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=87670#p494580): _"Channels that show a * in the upper right area use a graphic image, either part of the overhang graphic itself, or using one of the overhangLogo .png graphics."_

Comment: I also tried the solution with the character code, but only managed to get the characters 0-127 to work through the use of [Chr()](http://sdkdocs.roku.com/display/sdkdoc/BrightScript+Language+Reference#BrightScriptLanguageReference-84ChrchasIntegerasString). Also the U+272A character is a 5 pointed star while the Roku remote has a 6 pointed star.

Comment: @SiekermanTechnology, wow - i had no idea RokuCo themselves would be using such a hack to show `[*]` instead of adding it emoji-like to the system font. Btw great job on providing here the answers you found in the forum, +1.